# How to add or remove two input fields and store those inputs into an array in react?

Tags: arrays, reactjs, react-router

I want to add or remove input text fields and store them into an array. It is always taking the last input pair.

***Screenshot of my front end:***
[image: screenshot of my front end]

***Code:***

```
<form className="form-inline">
        {this.state.newData.map((data, index) => (
          <div id={`index-${index}`} className="form-group" >
            <AvField
                    placeholder="Item Name"
                    id={`index-${index}`}
                    type="text"
                    name="itemName"/>
            <AvField
                    placeholder="Item Value"
                    id={`index-${index}`}
                   type="text"
                   name="itemValue"
            />
            <Button style={{ margin: 7 }} onClick={this.handleDelete(index)} color="danger">
              {' '}
              -{' '}
            </Button>
          </div>
        ))}
        <Button style={{ margin: 7 }} onClick={this.addNew} color="success">
          {' '}
          +{' '}
        </Button>
        </form>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I assume you mean the delete is always taking the last value out of the array instead of the specified index? Try binding the handleDelete:

```
<Button style={{ margin: 7 }} onClick={this.handleDelete.bind(this, index)} color="danger">
  {' '}
  -{' '}
</Button>
```

Can maybe help some more with a little more detail on your code/what you are trying to accomplish.

Comment: No! when I'm submitting , it's taking the last input pairs values

Comment: @AvijitDas Where is your submit method?

Comment: saveEntity = (event, errors, values) => {
    if (errors.length === 0) {
      const { inventoryCategoryEntity } = this.props;
      const entity = {
        ...inventoryCategoryEntity,
        ...values
      };

   
      if (this.state.isNew) {
        this.props.createEntity(entity);
      } else {
        this.props.updateEntity(entity);
      }
      this.handleClose();
    }
  };